# Update sheets, create PDF, old data in pdf (google apps script)

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a strange bug i cannot seem to get my head around. I have a google sheets that I update with a apps script HTML page. Nothing fancy just some form with some input boxes. After inputting the fields and running the script it replaces values in my google sheets by looking up key values in the sheet and replacing the values in the next cell over.

```js
/*
 * Krijg alle verdeler data uit het formulier
 * @param form
 * @return data object
 */
function getVerdelerData(form) {
  var data = {
    BNX: form.bnx,
    AanvangDatum: form.aanvangDatum,
    AanvangUur: form.aanvangUur,
    EindUur: form.eindUur,
    Lijn: "Lijn " + form.lijn,
    Spoor: form.spoor,
    TPOBVL: form.tpobvl
  };

  return data;
}

/*
 * Al de functionaliteit voor het formulier
 * @param form
 * @return succes of fail
 */
function writeForm(form) {
  try {
    var verdelerSheetId = '.................';
    var verdelerData = this.getVerdelerData(form);

    // Open Verdeler spreadsheet
    var verdeler = SpreadsheetApp.openById(verdelerSheetId); //the ID of the spreadsheet you want to write to   

    this.writeVerdeler(verdelerData, verdeler);
    return this.success();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }
}

/*
 * Schrijf gegevens naar de verdeler ES bestand
 * @param data (van het formulier)
 * @param spreadsheet
 */
function writeVerdeler(data, spreadsheet) {

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Input");
  if (sheet != null) {
    Logger.log(sheet.getIndex());
  } 

  for(var i in data) {
    var checkRange = this.keyRange(i, sheet);
    if(checkRange != null) {
      var range = sheet.getRange(checkRange, 2); // 2 = B
      range.setValue(data[i]);
    }
  }
  this.createPDF(spreadsheet, "Output aanvraag", "Verdeler ES", true);
}

/*
 * Krijg de rij terug waar de gegevens moeten komen
 * @param value (de naam in de spreadsheet)
 * @param activeSheet
 * @return de correcte rij waar de value zich bevindt
 */
function keyRange(value, activeSheet) {
  var sheet = activeSheet;
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var keyValue = String(value);
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i][0] == keyValue){ // [0] because column A
      return i+1;
    }
  }
}

/*
 * Maak een pdf die past op de pagina
 * @param sheet
 * @param sheetName
 * @param pdfName
 * @param portrait (true of false)
 */
function createPDF(sheet, sheetName, pdfName, portrait) {
  var spreadsheetId = sheet;
  var sheetName = sheetName;
  var pdfName = pdfName + " " + Date();
  var pdfFolderId = '..................';
  var sheetId = spreadsheetId.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId();
  var url_base = spreadsheetId.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
  + '&gid=' + sheetId
  // following parameters are optional...
  // + '&range=A1:F12'
  + '&size=A4'               // paper size: legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=' + portrait  // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'             // fit to width, false for actual size
  + '&top_margin=0.50'
  + '&bottom_margin=0.50'
  + '&left_margin=0.50'
  + '&right_margin=0.50'
  + '&sheetnames=false' 
  + '&printtitle=false'
  + '&pagenumbers=false'    // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&gridlines=false'      // hide gridlines
  + '&fzr=true';            // false = do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  var url_options = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),}};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, url_options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(pdfFolderId);
  folder.createFile(blob);
}
```

After it has located and changed all the data in then takes the next tab in the google sheets and generates a PDF according to the data.

Most data comes out correctly but for one or another reason the last value it changes does not get updated. So one piece of the data is always wrong. I tried all sorts of things.

1. Adding a check that all the changes are done (no success)
2. Adding in a utilities.sleep(10000) (no success)
3. Changing the location of the this.createPDF(...) (no success)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Try SpreadsheetApp.flush() before creating PDF

Comment: This did the trick, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush), the method `flush`:

> Applies all pending Spreadsheet changes.
>
> Spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve
>   performance, such as when doing multiple calls to Range.getValue().
>   However, sometimes you may want to make sure that all pending changes
>   are made right away, for instance to show users data as a script is
>   executing.